# Get controller with a path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At this time i'm trying to get the controller with a path as a parameter

Then what I need is a method that returns the controller, something like

```
<%= get_controller(users_path) %>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do `<%= controller_name %>` only to get the controller name.

Comment: But doesn't It helps for only get the current path controller ?, exactly what I need is the controller based on a path as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me introduce you to `ActionDispatch`'s [`recognize_path`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet/recognize_path):

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(users_path)[:controller]
=> "users"
```

Please note that if you are outside a controller or view (such as in a model or in the console, for example), you need to first `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` before passing named helpers to the method. String routes (`"/users"` in this case) will work in any case.